# Selenium selecting option from the select tag not changing the state of other attributes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two `<select>` tags in my page and one of it is hidden.

```
<select class="" id="" oninput="onShowData(event, this)"></select>
<select class="" id="" name="" hidden></select>
```

Once i choose an option from the first  tag, the second  tag would get displayed (meaning the hidden attribute of the second `<select>` tag would be deleted dynamically).
However while automating it with Selenium Web driver choosing an option in the first  tag doesn't displays the second  tag (meaning the hidden attribute of the second `<select>` tag is not getting removed).

Comment: You probably need to click a slightly different element on your first click. Hard to say much more than that without any code or `html` to go off of.

Comment: Did you wait enough for the second `Select` to appear? Could you share the code that you are using for this scenario?

Comment: Please share the code that you are using to select this options

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you have chosen an option from the first `select` element add following code (which will  remove `hidden` attribute of the second `select` and make it visible) :

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('select2ID').removeAttribute('hidden')");
```

Note: you'll have to provide `Select` option 2's id in `getElementByID` function.